# different types of soil sensors?

Tags: soil

I am looking for soil sensors to be used for agriculture crops. Can you please guide me on what all available soil sensors commercially available and how their properties can be used in suggesting what to be grown.

Regards

Vinay

Comment: I don't think this is question is on topic for G&L but more for Agriculture http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114931/agriculture. Also, I don't think direct product recommendations are allowed on SE.

Comment: I am not asking for direct product , rather i would need help in finding technology which helps in extracting soil properties.

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question on Electrical Engineering SE - seriously!

Comment: Asked same in Electrical SE too.

Comment: I feel bad for you, because I'm not sure how we can help you. From what I saw in the description of Electrical Engineering, it seemed off-topic, and I'm not sure why you were advised to post it there. (I also noticed someone left you a rude comment, which seemed uncalled for.) I googled "soil sensors, types and technologies." Some farming sites came up. Maybe something there can help you.  We're really not trying to turn you away or hurt your feelings.

Answer (score 1):

Sensors are not so useful, without a "model" (so software), which BTW it is the most expensive part.

Unfortunately your question if off-topic (professional agriculture, which probably will never have a stack exchange site: the proposals lack of support [people who commit to ask and answer]).

I think you should start by checking some professional supplier (e.g. https://www.davisnet.com/solution/enviromonitor-affordable-field-monitoring-system/). Because they need to sell stuffs, usually they have good documentation.  Then it is up to you to check the "models" and the sensors for your specific use.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo. I am looking forward to write software for this, but i lack knowledge in agriculture. Can you please help me to find sensors and their respective properties which can be utilised in agriculture.

Comment: @Vinay: if you have not knowledge in agriculture, doesn't use sensors. Such sensor are not necessary. You eyes and experience are far better.  Such sensors are used to automatize (or on very large fields, where you can optimize what field to do today. [or used for research, where one should document and standardize environment]

Answer (score 1):

One of the more basic is a [tensiometer](http://hydropedologie.agrobiologie.cz/en-tenzometr.html), i.e. an accurate soil moisture meter (non-electrical in function, thus not confused by salts.) That will either tell you when to irrigate if irrigation is possible, or how much moisture you have available if irrigation is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Ecnerwal. Is there any literature /documents to find this study of when to irrigate ?

Comment: Most agriculture textbooks....and many websites, such as this one, for a shorter treatment. http://agriculture.vic.gov.au/agriculture/horticulture/vegetables/vegetable-growing-and-management/how-to-use-tensiometers